# Alamofire request crashes when trying to implement UI related Functions

Tags: swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire library for network calls
and whenever I try to to implement anything related to UI inside the request, It crashes
for example when I want to show dialog box it crashes

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters).responseString { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success:
            print("Validation Successful")
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
        print("Success: \(response.result.isSuccess)")
        print("Response String: \(String(describing: response.result.value) )")
        if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
            print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
        }
        self.showCallBackDialog()
    }
```

if I remove showCallBackDialog it works fine,I guarantee showCallBackDialog is working okay, It works when I use it outside Alamofire request

The error message:

```
2017-10-12 00:15:55.889747+0530 MagicHands[43034:8535265] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3694.4.18/UIApplication.m:1706
2017-10-12 00:15:55.905170+0530 MagicHands[43034:8535265] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: You should call UI related stuff in mainthread. Also, what's the crash message?

Comment: hmm...But i want to show dialog after the request gets completed 
Is there anyway i can connect showCallBackDialog to Main thread from the alamofire block?

Comment: Yes you can: `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.showCallBackDialog()}`. But showing the crash log should be helpful.

Comment: 2017-10-12 00:15:55.889747+0530 MagicHands[43034:8535265] *** Assertion failure in -[UIApplication _cachedSystemAnimationFenceCreatingIfNecessary:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3694.4.18/UIApplication.m:1706
2017-10-12 00:15:55.905170+0530 MagicHands[43034:8535265] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: "requires the main thread' That's the important part. Replace `self.showCallBackDialog()` with `DispatchQueue.main.async { self.showCallBackDialog()}`

Comment: still not working i tried this already

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'accessing _cachedSystemAnimationFence requires the main thread'
after using dispatchQueue